# Auto mount and dismount USB harddrive debian server

Tags: usb, hard-disk

I've read a few articles on how to automount USB devices with usbmount. I was just wondering about the following:

- the documentation states that when the USB device is removed it will automatically unmount the device. Do they mean remove as in literally pulling the device out of the server? (this would be nice to have as my father wants to pull the plug from time to time, he does not know how to work with ssh)

This is on a Debian machine.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Please don't ask multiple questions in a single post. I have edited and removed the other two questions (you can see them by clicking on the [edit history](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/166444/revisions) link), please post them as separate questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to don_crissti I found the answer to this question:

It is not recommended to pull the plug without properly unmounting the device. Even if usbmount claims that it unmounts the device for you. That does not mean however that it does not work. Unplugging the device without properly unmounting can result in dataloss. If you like to live risky then you'll have to keep a few rules in mind:

- Do not unplug the device when there are files bieing copied to it.
- Do not unplug the device short afterwards copying file to it.